# Can one transfer someone else's sin onto himself?

Tags: sin, reward-punishment

Can one accept the consequences of someone else's actions?
It would seem unfair and unlikely that one would be able to accept someone else's rewards. If that is true, does it also apply to accepting someone else's punishments?

Comment: By speaking Lashon Hara about someone, you get their sins. So, technically, yes.

Comment: from a Medrash I know of..."ויאמר להם שמעוני אחי ועמי, אם טוב בעיניכם דברי אבדיל את האנשים האלה מעדת בני ישראל ולא יהיה להם חלק ונחלה בקרב ישראל, אך אם תקבלו עליכם את העון. ויענו כלם ויאמרו נקבל עלינו העון אך כאשר דברת עשה"

Comment: opposite https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29045/759

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.27.13?with=all&lang=bi&aliyot=0

Comment: Isn't that along the lines of when a man/husband/father bears the iniquities of his wife or daughter's vow after hearing then some time after disallowing it?

Comment: Our rewards and punishments are not similar to tangible or intangible objects. They are not a currency in your account, they are not points on your scoreboard. They are a part of who you are. Can I transfer my life in this world and the next world onto another? The answer is obvious.

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93  (תרגום: אלו שמונה "בני" למה? שבעה – שהעלהו משבעה מדורי גיהנום. והאחרון – יש אומרים: כדי לקרב את ראשו לגופו ויש אומרים: כדי להביאו לעולם הבא)

Comment: @Tesvov "_Our rewards and punishments are not similar to tangible or intangible objects. They are not a currency in your account, they are not points on your scoreboard_". And yet, on Erev Yom Kippur, people have rosters waved over their heads, saying: "זה חליפתי זה תמורתי זה כפרתי זה התרנגול ילך למיתה ואני אלך לחיים טובים ארוכים ולשלום" ("This is my exchange, this is my substitute, this is my atonement. This rooster will go to its death, while I will enter and proceed to a good long life and to peace").

Comment: @Tamir it is a universally accepted understanding that the text of kapparot is not meant literally.

Comment: @יהודה I think that's a very good analogy. Rivka is saying to Yaakov, the punishment should come on me, because the decision to do it was mine and you are just obeying.

Comment: @Tesvov If the text of kapparot is not meant literally, what does it mean?

Comment: @TamirEvan - see Michoel's explanation here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/how-why-does-kaparot-work/62278#62278

Comment: @Tesvov (1) If you mean [the answer itself](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20375/1368), I agree with the first comment there: it makes the text a lie (which strengthens my request for the text's meaning).

Comment: @Tesvov (2) If you mean [his comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/how-why-does-kaparot-work/62278#comment48067_20375) ("'כפרה' does not denote 'atonement' but rather 'ransom'"), (a) I already commented there, and am awaiting clarification. Furthermore, (b) [his source](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9158&pgnum=155) also says: "וזה המכוון גם כאן בשם 'כפרה' שהעונש והפגע הנגזר על האדם יהי' עוף זה או דג זה תחתיו".

Comment: @Tamir https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allegory

Comment: @Tesvov O.K., so what is the meaning [behind the allegory] of the text said?