Can We Use Our Reward In The Next World Like Money In This World?
A story about the Vilna Ga’on appears in Halachic Man (on p.30 in the 1984 English edition). I feel like I’ve heard essentially the same story many times, told about various historical figures, although I cannot now remember. In Halachic Man, the author refers to the story as a folk legend.
In the story, the Vilna Ga’on is unable to obtain Hadassim that he needs to perform one of the commandments of Sukkot. He sends people out to search, and Hadassim are found, growing in a particular woman’s yard. She agrees to sell them to the Vilna Ga’on, but the price that she demands is the reward that the Vilna Ga’on should receive for performing the Mitzvah. He agrees to the price and is, surprisingly, very happy when performing the Mitzvah on these terms. He explains that he is now able to perform the Mitzvah not for the sake of receiving a reward.
I have several problems with this story.

In the internal logic, it seems strange that Hadassim are growing in this woman’s yard but no place else. The climate and soil permit cultivation, and need for Hadassim on Sukkot should have taken nobody by surprise.
Also in the internal logic, there seems to be no reason for the Vilna Ga’on to have been happy on this particular occasion, if he could have made the same arrangement on every occasion. Similarly, if any of you would like to assign to me all of the reward for your performance of Mitzvos, you need only say the word.
Stepping outside of the internal logic now, how could our reward in the next world be like money that we can spend in this world? Could we set up an economy on this basis, paying for groceries and babysitting with a share of our reward in the next life? Could a rich man go around to all of the poor people, buying their reward on the cheap, depending only on their misfortune in needing money? This way of thinking about reward is repellant in that it undermines the justice of reward and punishment, which is seemingly the whole point of reward and punishment.
The Vilna Ga’on died in 1797. The original Hebrew text of Halachic man was published in 1944. The English edition that I saw provides no source for the story.
I cannot think of any old telling of any comparable story. For example, in the story (Avodah Zarah 18) about the execution of Chanania Ben Tradyon, someone sacrifices his own life to help, after assurance that he will receive a share in the world to come, and the story then assures us that he did receive that reward. And in the relationship between Zevulun and Issachar that Rashi mentions (Gen 49:13, Deut 33:18), Zevulun works to support Issachar in learning; and everyone I ask seems to understand some sort of implication for the reward each party receives. But in these stories, everyone is genuinely doing something meritorious, and the reward could simply by commensurate with the desert. That seems clearly not the intention in the story of the Vilna Ga’on. In the Vilna Ga’on story, the idea seems to be that the woman is receiving more reward than her actions really recommend, simply because she drove a hard bargain; and her reward is at the expense of the party actually deserving of the reward, so that nobody seems to be getting reward according to his merit.

So, I ask you.
Can you point me to authoritative sources for this idea that while we live, we can use our future reward as money for the payment of our bills, so that in the end these arrangements will actually transfer reward from the otherwise deserving party to the otherwise undeserving party? Is there any way to improve the provenance of this Vilna Ga’on story, or comparable “Gedolim” stories? Are there relevant ancient, medieval or Renaissance versions?

I've heard a similar story about an esrog. But it sounds more like a Chassidic story than a Litvish story

@ClintEastwood I'm guessing you mean this one: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3801743/jewish/The-Stranger-Who-Wanted-to-Go-to-Heaven.htm

Here's what happened. R' Soloveichic realized that Jews would be spiritually lost after the Holocaust. To prevent them from falling down the path of chassidus (which could lead to false Messiah following), he took this story to inspire people to become misnagdim.

The premise behind your question is logically compelling. How can 'future reward' be transferred from one to another like a form of currency? And, indeed, there are numerous sources - most notably, R' Hai Gaon [quoted by Maharam Alashkar (Siman 101) and cited by R' Akiva Eger (Hil. Talmud Torah)], who decry the concept of buying or selling reward.
Your question asks for authoritative sources for such a concept. If you accept the Vilna Gaon as authoritative, you probably will be happy with a source from his disciple R' Chaim Volozhin. In Ruach Chaim (commentary to Avos, 1:1) R' Chaim Volozhin tells the story of the author of Turei Zahav (known as the 'Taz'), who 'donated' the reward of one study session to a sick child, who recovered in that merit.

A century before the Taz (1586-1667), Shiltei Giborim (d. 1557) in his glosses to Rif (Baba Kama 32b) indicates this idea - that one can effectively sell his divine reward for money - although he provides a caveat that the sale takes place prior to performing the mitzvah. [See, however, Shu"t Meishiv Davar 14 for a different understanding].

ולפ"ז יעלה יפה מה שכתבתי דאדם יכול למכור המצות שלו ויעלו לאיש הקונה
דהא יש להם ערך י' זהובים לאחר מיהו נראה דוקא מועיל הקנין במצוה שעתיד
לעשות אבל לא במצוה שעשה כבר

Imrei Binah (Responsa, Siman 13) attempts to reconcile the opinions by differentiating between two types of 'divine reward'. See also this answer

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96777/17563

The sick-child story does not seem very similar. The child is not selling something and receiving a share in the world to come in exchange. The Tzadik is rather saying that he regards the recovery of the child as the Tzadik's reward. That seems more like stories in the gemara in which a Tzadik is asked whether he would prefer one reward or another.

Your question: these arrangements will actually transfer reward from the otherwise deserving party to the otherwise undeserving party - this is a case of 'undeserving party' benifiting from the reward of the 'deserving party'
